# XPath - Get Attribute With Certain Value

Tags: xpath

My XPath expression appears to be slightly wrong. Here is a snippet of my XML..

```
<wd:Repository_Document_Reference wd:Descriptor="EIB_Input.zip">
                 <wd:ID wd:type="WID">VALUE 1</wd:ID>
                 <wd:ID wd:type="Document_ID">VALUE 2</wd:ID>
</wd:Repository_Document_Reference>
```

I am looking to extract 'VALUE 2' as a single output.

The current XPath I am is not working:

```
/wd:Repository_Document_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Document_ID']
```

Does my XPath need a slight tweak?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath selects

```
<wd:ID wd:type="Document_ID">VALUE 2</wd:ID>
```

from the XML you've shown.  In a context where this is evaluated as a string, it will indeed be

```
VALUE 2
```

If you wish to force it to be evaluated as a string, you can explicitly take the string value of your XPath:

```
string(/wd:Repository_Document_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Document_ID'])
```

However, there's a chance that the rest of your document, which you've not shown, is causing other complications.  Your XPath might be selecting multiple elements or no elements.  You have to make sure that your XPath is specific enough to only be selecting the element you want.  You also have to make sure that you've defined the namespaces prefix, `wd` properly.  Without knowing more about your actual example, we can't say.

Answer (score -1):

Try;
`/wd:Repository_Document_Reference/wd:ID[contains(@wd:type,"Document_ID")]`